Question regarding intersection of values of a function
This question is being asked in regards to the following problem
Solve: $x^2 - 4 - \lfloor x \rfloor = 0$
The solution for the above equation in my textbook is done by drawing the graph of both the functions and checking where they intersect.
This seems like a very bad way to solve the problem as one wont be able to do this for more complex problems of the sort.
Is  their a analytical way to solve the above question?
Any help would be appreciated!

The thing is $x^2 = \lfloor x \rfloor + 4$ and in general $x^2$ grows "faster" than $x$ or $\lfloor x \rfloor$, so this puts severe limits to the possible range of $x$.
If $x < 0$, for example $\lfloor x \rfloor \le -1$ and we have $x^2 \le -1 + 4 =3$ so $|x| \le \sqrt 3$ so $-2 < -\sqrt 3 \le x < 0$.
Likewise if $x \ge 3$ then $x^2 \ge 3x \ge x + 2\times 3 > x + 4 \ge \lfloor x \rfloor + 4$ so we have $x < 3$.
In the end we can reduce it to very few ranges.  (I can reduce it to two but five is pretty manageable too)
In these ranges $\lfloor x \rfloor$ will be a constant knowable value $k$ and we can easily solve $x^2 = k + 4$.
(For example if $-2 \le x < -1$ then $\lfloor x \rfloor = -2$ and we have to solve $x^2 = -2 + 4$.
So... have at it.

You may write $x = x_0 + \varepsilon$, where $x_0 = \lfloor x \rfloor$ and $0 \le \varepsilon < 1$. Then, the original equation becomes $x^2 = (x_0 + \varepsilon)^2 = x_0^2 + 2\varepsilon x_0 + \varepsilon^2 = x_0 + 4$, which you can solve for either $x_0$ (and determine which values of $\varepsilon$ imply an integer $x_0$) or $\varepsilon$ (and similarly determine which values of $x_0$ allow $0 \le \varepsilon < 1$).
